# Continuity of real value function only defined at rational points

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

Novice in continuity, if $f(x)$ is defined as

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, &x\text{ is rational}\\
1, &x=\sqrt 2\\
\text{undefined}, &\text{others}
\end{cases}
$$

would it be continous at the point $(0, f(0))$?

since it's undefined at irrational points around $0$, I think I should ignore them.

or I should only discuss continuity in a continuous interval?

I'm confused with the definition and my intuition, sorry if this question is silly (>_<)

Comment: The more advanced definition of continuous specifies function defined on a certain set.  In this case, if our set is the domain of $f$, then $f$ is continuous at $0$.  Indeed, it is continuous everywhere except $\sqrt2$.

Comment: It is continuous everywhere it is defined being that it is a rational point and not $\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of continuity is defined only on the points of the domain of a function. In your case, the domain is $\mathbb{Q} \bigcup \{\sqrt{2}\}$. In that case, we have, given $\varepsilon > 0$, if $|x| \leq \varepsilon$ and $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then
$$|f(x) - f(0)| = |0 - 0| = 0 \leq \varepsilon$$
hence f is continuous on the point $(0,0)$.

What is to be considered here, is that continuity is a topological definition, therefore it is variant under a change of topology. As your function is not defined on the whole Real line, it makes no sense to debate its continuity in it.